# Client SQL in Python and crontab

Tags: python, sql, cron, mysql-python, pymysql

I have some script in Python which are executed by crontab on Raspbian.
I use the MySQLdb library for request in the local network.

All scripts work fine if i launch them directly, by Python-IDLE, or in the console.
**But if they are launched by cron, those who just execute "INSERT" requests work, but those who execute "SELECT" request don't work.**

I haven't found a clear solution, but it seems that crontab doesn't execute the same configuration of the SQL client as the user. 
Maybe i have to change the path before all request ? (looking for a "./my.cnf" ?

tested with library MySQLdb and PyMySQL

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# importations  
import os
import time
import sys
import pymysql as sql  # or MySQLdb as...
from os import path as os_path

#-----------------------------------------------------------------#
#  constants : use your own values / utilisez vos propres valeurs #
#-----------------------------------------------------------------#
PATH_THERM = "/home/pi/Documents/" #path to this script
DB_SERVER ='192.168.0.59'       # MySQL : IP server 
DB_USER='user'                    # MySQL : user
DB_PWD='password'              # MySQL : password
DB_BASE='capteurs'              # MySQL : database name

def log(texte):
    datation = time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

    logue = open('log_test.txt','a')
    txt = "\n" + datation + "\t" + texte
    txt = txt.encode('utf-8')
    logue.write(txt)
    logue.close()

def query_temp():
    datebuff = time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

    db = sql.connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PWD, DB_BASE)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT sonde2,date FROM `PiTemp` ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 1""")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    print datebuff, u" : Dernière température de l'eau :", rows[0][0], u"°C"
    log(u"lecture température SQL - ok")

    a = rows[0][0]
    b =  rows[0][1]
    return (a, b)


#----------------------------------------------------------#
#             principal code                               #
#----------------------------------------------------------#

PATH=os_path.abspath(os_path.split(__file__)[0])
os.chdir(PATH)
log('start')
log(PATH)
txt = str(query_temp()[0])
log(txt)
```

crontab :

```
*/1 * * * * python /home/pi/Documents/180623_test.py
```

Comment: tested on Jessie and Stretch, Rapsberry Pi 2 and 3B+, tested with "sudo python...", tested with a crontab like :

*/1 * * * * cd /home/pi/Documents/ && python "180623_test_SQL.py"
does not work neither of them

Comment: pls define * does not work*, do you run cron as 'you' or as another user ?

Comment: \`PiTemp\` ? ... is that allowed ?

Comment: does not work neither launched as a service...

Comment: tested with the user : 'pi", tested with 'sudo'

Comment: 'PiTemp' is the name of one of my SQL-table (stand for 'temperatures followed by the Pi'), it works with other scripts and configurations

Comment: 'does not work' means that the script launched from cron don't execute entirely. With the log file we can guess that the SQL request doesn't have the good configuration or the good rights. The python libraries don't speak of those points.

Comment: catch all your logging by using: */1 * * * * python /home/pi/Documents/180623_test.py > /tmp/debug.log 2>&1 and check the  output.

Comment: */1 * * * * python /home/pi/Documents/180623_test.py > /tmp/debug.log 2>&1 :  "25-06-2018 Erreur connection serveur SQL..."

Comment: without exception :                          print (u"Alerte, tous à poil !")  
                UnicodeEncodeError : 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

Found raeson of fail, the print passed by cron don't encode/decode the same as the console (!??).

> ... print (u"Alerte, tous à poil !") UnicodeEncodeDecode Error !

Strange, looks like cron doesn't encode / decode the same than the user.... (!?)

**Solved with no latin characters in print, or print passed by try/except...**